# How to make Card component clickable?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I use the Ant Design for my WebApp. For the [Card](https://ant.design/components/card/), there's a hoverable prop that make the card seams clickable but there's no onClick prop. How do I make it really clickable?

This is my Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, Avatar, Icon, Button, Divider } from 'antd';
import EventDetailsDrawer from '../ui/EventDetailsDrawer';

const { Meta } = Card;

class EventCard extends Component {

render() {
    return (
        <div onClick={alert("Hello from here")}>
            <Card
                hoverable
                cover={<img alt="example" src="https://assetsnffrgf-a.akamaihd.net/assets/m/1102015169/univ/art/1102015169_univ_lsr_lg.jpg" />}
                bodyStyle={{ marginBottom: "-5px" }}
                >
                    <Meta
                        //avatar={<Avatar src="https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png" />}
                        avatar={<Button type="primary" shape="circle-outline">{this.props.owner}</Button>}
                        title={this.props.title}
                        description={this.props.descp}
                    />
                    <Divider style={{ marginLeft: "0px" }}></Divider>
                    <p><Icon type="clock-circle" style={{ fontSize: "15px", color: "#1890FE" }} theme="outlined" /><span style={{ marginLeft: "15px" }} />{this.props.date}</p>
                    <p><Icon type="environment" style={{ fontSize: "15px", color: "#1890FE" }} theme="outlined" /><span style={{ marginLeft: "15px" }} />{this.props.location}</p>
        </Card>
                    <EventDetailsDrawer></EventDetailsDrawer>
        </div>
                );
            }
        }

export default EventCard
```

I try to make a dive (around the Card) clickable, but the Code runs immediately after the app is loaded, since I pack each card into a list item. How to make Card component clickable?

Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Putting `onClick={() => console.log('CLICK')}` on the Card component with the latest Ant Design seems to work fine.

Comment: While I think this works, I think implementing with `<div>` is working outside the utility of the library. Instead, per my answer, wrap with `<Link>` element. Happy coding!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Notice that what you are attaching to the div's `onClick` listener is the value returned by `alert` and not actually a function that should be run whenever the div is clicked.

Try changing this:

```
<div onClick={alert("Hello from here")}>
```

To this:

```
<div onClick={() => alert("Hello from here")}>
```

Comment: While I think this works, I think implementing with `<div>` is working outside the utility of the library. Instead, per my answer, I wrap with `<Link>` element. Happy coding!

Answer (score 7):

I came here with a similar question.  What worked for me is to wrap the `<Card>` with a `<Link>` component.   Also, setting the `hoverable` property on the card will give it an effect that has it appear "clickable".  For example:

```
<Link to={'/customer/list'}>
   <Card hoverable>

      // ... removed for brevity...

   </Card>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, onClick expects a function, and is invoking when render() is executed.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Card, Avatar, Icon, Button, Divider} from 'antd';
import EventDetailsDrawer from '../ui/EventDetailsDrawer';

const {Meta} = Card;

class EventCard extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={() => {alert("Hello from here")}}>
                <Card
                    hoverable
                    cover={<img alt="example"
                            src="https://assetsnffrgf-a.akamaihd.net/assets/m/1102015169/univ/art/1102015169_univ_lsr_lg.jpg"/>}
                            bodyStyle={{marginBottom: "-5px"}}
                >
                    <Meta
                        avatar={<Button type="primary" shape="circle-outline">{this.props.owner}</Button>}
                        title={this.props.title}
                        description={this.props.descp}
                    />
                    <Divider style={{marginLeft: "0px"}}></Divider>
                    <p>
                        <Icon type="clock-circle" style={{fontSize: "15px", color: "#1890FE"}} theme="outlined"/>
                        <span style={{marginLeft: "15px"}}/>
                        {this.props.date}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <Icon type="environment" style={{fontSize: "15px", color: "#1890FE"}} theme="outlined"/>
                        <span style={{marginLeft: "15px"}}/>
                        {this.props.location}
                    </p>
                </Card>
                <EventDetailsDrawer></EventDetailsDrawer>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default EventCard
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the antd `Card` already supports `onClick`, you can pass this `onClick` to your custom property like below:

```js
// EventCard.js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from './propTypes';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { Card } from 'antd';

const { Meta } = Card;

const EventCard = ({
    myOnClick,
    ...restProps
}) => {
    return (
        <Card
            hoverable
            bodyStyle={{ marginBottom: "-5px" }}
            cover={<img alt="example" src="https://assetsnffrgf-a.akamaihd.net/assets/m/1102015169/univ/art/1102015169_univ_lsr_lg.jpg" />}
            onClick={() => myOnClick()}
        >
            <Meta 
                title={this.props.title}
                description={this.props.descp} />
        </Card>
    );
};

EventCard.propTypes = {
    myOnClick: PropTypes.func,
};

export default EventCard;
```

Where `propTypes` is:

```js
// propTypes.js
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default {
  ...PropTypes,
  ID: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number]).isRequired,
  component: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.func]),
  date: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.instanceOf(Date), PropTypes.string]),
};
```

Then you can use it like:

```js
myClickHandler = (params) => {
    console.log("Click!!!");
});

render() {
    return (
        <EventCard myOnClick={()=> this.myClickHandler("any parameters")} />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind make a div clickable is a very bad practice in terms of accessibility, because without mouse, you cannot tab to the card nor use enter or space to click the card.

My recommendation would be wrap the card with an unstyled button, so you can take all the advantages of a button (click, tab, keyboard support)

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Card, Avatar, Icon, Button, Divider } from 'antd';
    import EventDetailsDrawer from '../ui/EventDetailsDrawer';

    const { Meta } = Card;

    class EventCard extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={alert("Hello from here")} className="unstyled-button">
                <Card />
            </button>
                    );
                }
            }

    export default EventCard
```

css

```
 .unstyled-button {
       border:none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works well for me:

```
  <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardActionArea
        onClick={(evt) => {
          console.log(evt.target);
          sayHi(evt);
        }}
      >
        <CardContent>
          <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
            {props.job.label}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
      <CardActions></CardActions>
    </Card>
```

and sayHi is

```
  function sayHi(props) {
    history.push({
      pathname: "/another-page/",
      state: { jobId: props.job.id },
    });
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no possible, to make `onClick` here. You need to call an `onClick` event inside the `Card` component. Then if you need to pass some props, or use logic, just pass the function/content in the prop to `Card`. Something like that - `<Card handleClick={this.handleClickMethod} />`. Then inside `Card` component you can call the `handleClick` function.

Hope that helped you

Answer (score -1):

maybe this will help:

```
youHandleClickFunc = (params) => {
console.log('you need params from Card', params)
}

render() {
        return (
          <Card handleClick={()=> this.youHandleClickFunc(param)}/>
        )
}
```